# Value not passing when redirecting from controller to another controller while passing data in MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Is it possible to pass data from one controller to another? When my second controller is called the int id is showing the WRONG value:

I have one controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
  return RedirectToAction("New", "NewProducts", id);
}
```

NewProductsController:

```
public string New(int id)//    <--------id never has correct number when called
{

  return "value: " + id;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use either a RouteValueDictionary or an anonymous type with an id property for the route values otherwise it will use the properties on the `Int32` object `id` to fill the route values dictionary.

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
  return RedirectToAction("New", "NewProducts", new { id = id } );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will work

public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
      return RedirectToAction("New?id=" + id, "NewProducts");
}